# spring recursive associations get "duplicate" children

Tags: java, recursion, spring-data

i'm using spring mongodb to do a recursive association of the entity PimEntity 
here is my files : 
PimEntityDefinition.java

```
abstract class PimEntityDefinition {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String code;
    private String type;

    public PimEntityDefinition() {
    }
```

PimEntity.java

```
public class PimEntity extends PimEntityDefinition {
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<PimEntity> subEntities;
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<PimAttribute> attributes;
```

and when i call the findAll function 
this.entitiesRepository.findAll();

i get :

```
[
 {
        "id": "59ed96e4e4b014bdcd2fcc8f",
        "code": "tree1",
        "type": "tree",
        "subEntities": [
            {
                "id": "59ed9702e4b014bdcd2fcc90",
                "code": "tree1.1",
                "type": "tree",
                "subEntities": [],
                "attributes": null
            }
        ],
        "attributes": null
    },
        {
                "id": "59ed9702e4b014bdcd2fcc90",
                "code": "tree1.1",
                "type": "tree",
                "subEntities": [],
                "attributes": null
    }]
```

How can i get the "59ed9702e4b014bdcd2fcc90" only once ?

Thanks for your help.

I added the parents attribute like @Noixes suggested but i have an infinite loop 
with or without the lazy param.

```
public class PimEntity extends PimEntityDefinition {
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<PimEntity> parents;
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<PimEntity> subEntities;
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<PimAttribute> attributes;
```

getAll gives :

```
[ {
  "id" : "59edea6ce4b0df77770c7374",
  "code" : "tree1",
  "type" : "tree",
  "parents" : [ ],
  "subEntities" : [ {
    "id" : "59edea8de4b0df77770c7375",
    "code" : "tree1.1",
    "type" : "tree",
    "parents" : [ {
      "id" : "59edea6ce4b0df77770c7374",
      "code" : "tree1",
      "type" : "tree",
      "parents" : [ ],
      "subEntities" : [ {
        "id" : "59edea8de4b0df77770c7375",
        "code" : "tree1.1",
        "type" : "tree",
        "parents" : [ {
          "id" : "59edea6ce4b0df77770c7374",
          "code" : "tree1",
          "type" : "tree",
          "parents" : [ ],
          "subEntities" : [ {
            "id" : "59edea8de4b0df77770c7375",
            "code" : "tree1.1",
            "type" : "tree",
            "parents" : [ {
              "id" : "59edea6ce4b0df77770c7374",
                ...
```

@DBRef(lazy = true) private List parents Not working ?